# Matrix converting to a list in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

There is a txt file with Wolfram Mathematica style of matrix (it can be 1000+ strings):

```
{-0.00036, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0.0003, -1.00026, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0.0002, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

I need to make the nested list from it to make further calculations in python. 
The result should be -

```
s=[[[0.00036], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],[[0.0003],.. and so on
```

I am totally new with python, can you help me?

Comment: Is there always exactly one row of the array on one line of the text file?

Comment: No, sometimes it can jump, but there are still  {}

Comment: Your original data as posted under Ashwinis answer contains arithmetic expressions! You should consider using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string or something like that.

Comment: Yes sorry, i didn't noticed it, my fault. Can you help me to handle with original data? That file on dropbox have all that i need, for sure.

Comment: I hope I have addressed that issue with my edits. Please also look at the documentation I referenced. If you feel your problem is solved, please consider accepting one of the answers by clicking the check mark.

Comment: @DmitriyButenko: Consider using NumPy if you want to do further calculations. It will provide both speed and flexibility when working with matrices of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code which allows the line breaks to be anywhere you like. But the entries can only be floating point numbers.

```
f = open("filename", "r")

buff = ""
array = []
for line in f:
    buff += line
    if "}" in line:
        start = buff.index("{")
        end = buff.index("}")
        array.append([float(val.strip()) for val in buff[start+1:end].split(",")])
        buff = buff[end+1:]

f.close()

print(array)
```

If you need arithmetic expression to the extend of one level of multiplication, you can do:

```
import operator

def prod(lst):
    return reduce(operator.mul, lst, 1)

f = open("filename", "r")

buff = ""
array = []
for line in f:
    buff += line
    if "}" in line:
        start = buff.index("{")
        end = buff.index("}")
        array.append([prod(float(factor.strip()) for factor in val.split("*")) for val in buff[start+1:end].split(",")])
        buff = buff[end+1:]

f.close()

print(array)
```

To understand what is going on, look at [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [str.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for a start.

Comment: Yeah, that worked for a file without n*m structures, thanks! Well, there is still a problem with n*m parsing.

Comment: @DmitriyButenko: I added that now too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That totally solved my problem, and also thanks for links, now i've got how does it work.

Answer (score 2):

`eval` is evil, but sometimes it has its place. Because your input data contains arithmetic expressions, `eval` is the easiest way to convert it.

Naturally, **do not run this code on untrusted input** because it may compromise your computer. (If it's all stuff you generate out of Mathematica, you should be pretty safe).

Here's the code:

```
m = eval('[' + text.replace('{','[').replace('}',']') + ']')
m = [[[x] for x in row] for row in m]
```

Running this on the `111.txt` file (using `text = open('111.txt').read()`) yields the expected result:

```
[[[-0.00036], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0.0003], [-1.00026], [2], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0.0002], [-2], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[1e-05], [0], [0], [-1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [1e-05], [0], [0], [-1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[5e-05], [0], [0], [0], [0], [-0.01], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [5e-05], [0], [0], [0], [0], [-0.01], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.01], [0], [-0.000344], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.01], [0.0003], [-1.000244], [2], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.0002], [-2], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1e-05], [0], [0], [-1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1e-05], [0], [0], [-1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [3.4e-05], [0], [0], [0], [0], [-0.01], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [3.4e-05], [0], [0], [0], [0], [-0.01], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.01], [0], [-0.000328], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.01], [0.0003], [-1.000228], [2], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.0002], [-2], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1e-05], [0], [0], [-1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1e-05], [0], [0], [-1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1.8e-05], [0], [0], [0], [0], [-0.01], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1.8e-05], [0], [0], [0], [0], [-0.01], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.01], [0], [-0.0003], [1], [0]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.01], [0.0003], [-1.0002], [2]], [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0.0002], [-2]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('filename') as f:
    lis = [[[abs(literal_eval(item))] for item in 
                     line.rstrip('},\n').lstrip('{').split(', ')] for line in f]
    print lis
...     
[[[0.00036], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0.0003], [1.00026], [2], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0.0002], [2], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]]
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TwilightWind/Desktop/mas/prog.pyw", line 6, in <module>
    item in line.rstrip('},\n').lstrip('{').split(', ')] for line in f]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    0},
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished]`

Comment: @DmitriyButenko Please you post the actual content of the file, my answer works fine for the sample data.

Comment: @Ashwini: In the comments the OP says that rows may span multiple lines. That might be the problem.

Comment: @unutbu Actual data contains something like `3.40*0.00001`, which is I guess raising the error.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary just cleared the matrix from n*m like structures, but that didn't help. Anyways such structures can also have place.

Comment: @Ashwini: The lines end with `\r`, not `\n`.

Comment: @DmitriyButenko replace `line.rstrip('},\n')` with `line.rstrip('},\r\n').`